# Problem adding new child row to parent row; new row always added to bottom of sheet

Tags: smartsheet-api

I'm trying to add a new indented row as a child of an existing row and it just adds a new row to the bottom of the sheet instead of indented underneath parent row.

```
new_row = ssc.models.Row()
new_row.cells.append({
    'column_id':5050181304510340,
    'parentId':1379272254089092,
    'strict':False,
    'value':"test_value",    

})
response = ssc.Sheets.add_rows(6110498509875076, [new_row])
```

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like you have a typo in one of the property names. Try changing `parentId` to `parent_id` instead.

Also worth mentioning that the [Specify Row Location](https://smartsheet-platform.github.io/api-docs/#specify-row-location) section of the docs contains some good info about how to set various row properties to specify row position. (Mentioning this here mainly for the benefit of others who may find this thread later while looking for info about row positioning).

Comment: it wouldnt work changing to  'parent_Id':1379272254089092, i had to add the line new_row.parent_id = 1379272254089092 in order for it to work, but this helped me figure it out. thank you!  i had looked at the api doc in the link you sent previously but this was the example syntax they provided ("parentId": 8896508249565060} . confusing.

Comment: Glad you figured it out - thanks for the update! The examples in that section of the docs are actually showing JSON syntax (e.g., `parentId`); the Python SDK uses slightly different naming convention for property names (e.g., `parent_id`). For future reference (if there's ever any question), looking at the files in the [**models** folder of the Python SDK on GitHub](https://github.com/smartsheet-platform/smartsheet-python-sdk/tree/master/smartsheet/models) is a reliable way to know the property names you should use.

Comment: FWIW, I just noticed that the beginning of your comment reads ***it wouldn't work changing to 'parent_Id':1379272254089092*** -- using `parent_Id` (with a capital **I**) won't work -- but if you use `parent_id` (with a lowercase **i**), I'd suspect it should work -- even within the code structure you originally posted in your question.

Comment: Sorry deleted last comment cause i couldnt edit.   Actually changing to lower case (parent_id) while structured as in the original post did not work :(

Answer (score 0):

OMFG...been working for 2 days trying to return the parent and sibling and turns out it's a typo in the docs. This post is $$$

```
print(row.parent_id)
print(row.sibling_id)
print(row.row_number)
```